# C# ASP Control Panel Link Visible Only To Role Admin

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i make a link only visible for an admin? As i want to have a control panel link on my webpage, so if a user logs in and he is in the role group "admin" the link will become visible.

Comment: Please don't use the Classic ASP tag for .NET questions. Classic ASP is a technology predating .NET and does not support C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C# under asp.net, in your code behind ie

```
private void Page_Load (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // ... previous code ...

    // Add the following code:
    if (Context.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        myLink.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        myLink.Visible = false;
    }

    // ... following code ...
}
```

You can take a look at this link, may can be helpful [Forms Authentication in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx)
Even if it is a link to the framework 2.0, the principle of operation is the same

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your admin group has a unique ID in a database, I use something along the lines of:

```
<% If intLoggedInUserGroupID = 1 Then Response.Write "<a href=""nimda.asp"">Admin Page</a>" %>
```

Comment: How did you get `intLoggedInUserID`?

Comment: I'd read it from the DB when they log in, along with a couple of other variables which may be required by the site. Depends on what you're doing really :)

Comment: Sorry, I replied when this post was still in the classic-asp section, it's been moved to .net now - not sure of the relevancy of my original answer now...

Comment: The OP also tagged it as `C#`, so I edited to `ASP.NET` instead of `Classic`. You _may_ be correct, but the OP needs to confirm.

Comment: I believe the OP means a local admin on the machine (or from Active Directory)

Answer (score 0):

Your question leaves to many blank ends...

Are you using a server side linkbutton or HTML anchor?
Do you want it to be handled server side or client side?

Anyway, the baseline to the solution is that you have to know as which role the user is logged in when you approach the code that generates the HTML for the link. This can be done in several ways.

Then you can do whatever you desire with that link according to your needs. Als this can be done in several ways.